# Upload large files with Dropnet issue

Tags: c#, .net, rest, dropnet

I'm using Dropnet library in Visual Studio 2010 and I've connected my project with Dropbox. When I try to use upload with files smaller than 4MB it's ok but when the files are larger there is a problem. I've searched and found a sollution, to add this code in web.config:

```
<system.web> 
  <httpRuntime executionTimeout="1000" maxRequestLength="104857600"/> 
</system.web>
```

and this:

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="104857600"/>
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

So this should allow me to upload files smaller than 100MB, I've succeeded with some files around 10MB but when I try around 50MB and smaller, somehow it gets stuck, no error or anything, and no matter what number I put in maxRequestLength and maxAllowedContentLength it's still the same. Please help. My code is:

```
if (filMyFile.PostedFile!=null)
  {
     Stream stream = filMyFile.PostedFile.InputStream;
     int sLen = filMyFile.PostedFile.ContentLength;
     byte[] binaryData = new byte[sLen];
     int n = stream.Read(binaryData, 0, sLen);
     _client.UploadFile("/Folder/", filMyFile.PostedFile.FileName, binaryData);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The UploadFile method returns a DropNet.Models.MetaData. In my experience, if the upload is not successful, then the UploadFile method returns null. If the call is successful, then it returns an object.